# Pandas: How to update only up to n rows if condition is matched

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I need to update values of column B only for [:1000] positive matches. How can I implement this in the most robust and simple way?

```
    condition_mask =  (df["A"] >= from) & (df["A"] < to)
    df.loc[condition_mask,'B'] = some_value
```

Comment: Please add a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do that. I'm using synthetic data for demonstration.

```
# Create data: 
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.random.randint(0, 5, 10), 
                  "b": np.random.randint(0, 5, 10)}) 
print(df)

   a  b
0  4  1
1  0  0
2  0  2
3  3  3
4  2  4
5  3  3
6  2  3
7  1  4
8  0  0
9  2  3
```

The actual solution (in a couple of steps, for clarity):

```
mask = df.a >= 2
df["mask_counter"] = df.groupby(mask).cumcount()
df.loc[mask & (df.mask_counter <= 2), "b"] = 5
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  mask_counter
0  4  5             0
1  0  0             0
2  0  2             1
3  3  5             1
4  2  5             2
5  3  3             3
6  2  3             4
7  1  4             2
8  0  0             3
9  2  3             5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: I'm asking You how to update only N rows matching the condition in the most robust way. I can't understand what the purpose of your example. Lets say that I have 10000 records in df. In column A there is 1000 rows matching the condition. And I need to update only 100 of 1000 that match.

Comment: But you just implemented the same action as I did, just in another way. that's not the answer

Answer (score -1):

sample code :
Selecting all the rows from the given dataframe in which ‘Percentage’ is greater than 80 using basic method.

```
 # importing pandas 
import pandas as pd 

record = { 

'Name': ['Ankit', 'Amit', 'Aishwarya', 'Priyanka', 'Priya', 'Shaurya' ], 
'Age': [21, 19, 20, 18, 17, 21], 
'Stream': ['Math', 'Commerce', 'Science', 'Math', 'Math', 'Science'], 
'Percentage': [88, 92, 95, 70, 65, 78] } 

# create a dataframe 
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(record, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Stream', 'Percentage']) 

print("Given Dataframe :\n", dataframe) 

# selecting rows based on condition 
rslt_df = dataframe[dataframe['Percentage'] > 80] 

print('\nResult dataframe :\n', rslt_df)
```

Comment: I'm asking You how to update only N rows matching the condition in the most robust way.